# C++ class member function and callback from C API

Tags: c++, callback, pointer-to-member, member-functions

I am trying to learn how to call this `write_data(…)` function from the `funmain()` function in the class as shown in the code bellow. (I know this program works if I just list these two functions without putting it inside a class).

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data)` line gives me error and wouldn’t let me call the write_data(…) function. Can you please correct my code and tell me how I can achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
error C3867: 'go_website::write_data': function call missing argument list; use '&go_website::write_data' to create a pointer to member
```

---

```
//Microsoft Visual Studio 10 in C++
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

extern "C" typedef size_t curl_write_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
class go_website
{
public:
static curl_write_callback write_data;

void funmain()
{
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "http://www.shorturl.com/";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "C:\\bbb.txt";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &write_data); 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}};

extern "C" size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) 
{
size_t written;
written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
return written;
}

int main()
{
   go_website a;
   a.funmain();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message you are receiving. Saying "this line gives me error" doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines won't work:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, fp);
```

The second is the easiest to fix: `fp` is a file pointer, not a function, you're setting the wrong attribute, I guess you want [`CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTWRITEDATA).

For the callback function, you need a function pointer.  The name of an ordinary function automatically decays to its address, although using the address-of operator (`&functionname`) is cleaner.

Class member functions do not automatically decay.  In fact, a non-static class member function is totally incompatible with a normal function pointer, since there's no way to handle `this`.  Luckily you don't need a non-static member function, since no non-static members are used inside the callback.

<strike>Make the callback function `static` [**and`extern "C"`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/592205/103167):</strike>

```
extern "C" typedef size_t curl_write_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);

class go_website
{
public:
    static curl_write_callback write_data;

    // ...
};

extern "C" size_t go_website::write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
   size_t written;
   written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
   return written;
}
```

and then take its address, using the address-of operator and fully-qualified function name:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &go_website::write_data);
```

This part was even explained in the error message.  But it didn't tell you that you needed `static` or `extern "C"`, this is the problem with variable argument lists, they aren't typesafe.

After reading the Standard (section 7.5 `[dcl.link]`, and especially paragraph 4 and its examples), this isn't allowed.  The member function still has C++ language linkage, for both its name (not important) and its type (this is the deal-breaker).

You have to use a global function for the callback:

```
extern "C" size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
   size_t written;
   written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
   return written;
}
```

and then pass a pointer to it:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &write_data);
```

Comment: @Bet Voigt Thanks a lot for all the information. It complied fine and run. But while running, it crashed and give me the following error: `Unhandled exception at 0x56abe4f8 (msvcr100d.dll) in WebRead.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.` I can't seems to use `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`. It says `identifier CURLOPT_WRITEDATA is undefined`

Comment: @NewGuy: I just fixed some stuff, which may or may not make any difference.

Comment: @NewGuy: Also, the documentation says that option used to be called `CURLOPT_FILE`.

Comment: @Bet Voigt when I use `typedef extern "C" ....` at the top, it says `Error: linkage specification is not allowed` under the word extern

Comment: @NewGuy: Try turning it around so it's `extern "C" typedef` instead?

Comment: @NewGuy: Actually, after reading the standard, it's impossible for a member function to have "C" language linkage, which the callback requires.  So you have to use a global function for this :(

Comment: @Bet Voigt I have updated my original code and that method didn’t work. But Thanks for all the information and your time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @NewGuy: In my revised answer, you don't need a typedef at all.  Just move the `extern "C"` function before the class definition, and things should be working.

Answer (score 10):

It is possible http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Using_C_non_static_functions_f

```
 // f is the pointer to your object.
 static YourClass::func(void *buffer, size_t sz, size_t n, void *f)
 {
   // Call non-static member function.
   static_cast<YourClass*>(f)->nonStaticFunction();
 }
 // This is how you pass pointer to the static function:
 curl_easy_setopt(hcurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, YourClass:func);
 curl_easy_setopt(hcurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, this);
```

Comment: Brilliant, a pointer to the FAQ. I hope that was added after this question. Also, I suspect Ben Voigt could explain why this violates the standard(s) in five different ways :) But it worked on my machine {tm}

Answer (score 1):

> I know this program works if I just list these two functions without putting it inside a 
>   class

If it works outside of a class, but not inside, then you likely need to use the "this" pointer.

```
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, this->write_data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the infor. but `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, this->write_data);` didn't work

Comment: It's seems that you have to set function as static function

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want the WRITEFUNCTION to be a member function of your class. However, curl doesn't know which instance of the class to call it on. You need to create a static function that you pass to WRITEFUNCTION and then pass your this pointer as the CURLOPT_WRITEDATA parameter. Then in your static member function you can use the user_data pointer (which is your "this" from WRITE_DATA)  as the instance of the class.

Maybe this question will help: [curl WRITEFUNCTION and classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224722/curl-writefunction-and-classes)

Comment: I like this, but he needs to get the static member function callback working first, and he isn't actually using any member data anyway.

Comment: Actually, a static member function can't be used here at all.