# How do you use libcurl to get the output of a website?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I've been recently writing a program that I will want to request and receive information from URLs. For example:
    http://www.example.com/getRecords.asp?name=Jack&surname=Jackson

If that website responded by printing
    exists=true or exists=false

It would display on the terminal
    The user exists! or The user does not exist!

Also, it would be good if the person using the program could type in the variables themselves, e.g
    Name to check: Chuck Surname to check: Norris
    http://www.example.com/getRecords.asp?name=Chuck&surname=Norris

But there's another thing, if for example the test returns true, the website also says
    exists=true&age=30
It would be good to be able to print this other variable on the screen or even save it to a file.

If you can help please answer down below, or send me a link to an **understandable** tutorial on how to use libcurl. Thanks.

EDIT: Thank you for your answers! I have also figured out the variable part on my own.

Comment: If the preschool side of libcurl ([The Easy Interface](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/)) were any easier they would write the code *for* you. Did you go through [*their* documentation and samples](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html)?

Comment: please show what did you try so far! http://sscce.org ! ;-)

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig I will read it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should take a look to this sample code from the [libcurl Example source codes](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) :

[sepheaders.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/sepheaders.html)

Then change the URL

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
```

and implement your own logic in :

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
```

Then you may want to save the server answer in a std::string :

[curl WRITEFUNCTION and classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4226267/420446)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed :). Also thank you WhozCraig for a similair answer :)